# cumtrapz got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

Tags: python, scipy

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html#scipy.integrate.cumtrapz) I found an example of using integrate.cumtrapz(), but it doesn't work for me - when I try to set initial=0 in

```
y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(y, x, initial=0)
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: cumtrapz() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What version of Python do you have?

Comment: @SomeKittens Python 2.7.3, installed scipy from ubuntu/mint repos

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Apparently, yes. It means "Cumulative trapezoidal numerical integration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of scipy are you running? I've scipy 0.10.1, and the keyword `initial` is not recognized either. Moreover, the docstring does not have it either, while the source code for scipy 0.11 (which you linked) has it. Which leads me to a guess that it's something which was added in v 0.11.

Indeed:

```
>>> import scipy.integrate as si
>>> si.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.pyc'
```

then checking the source (which is in `quadrature.py`) --- the signature is

```
 def cumtrapz(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=-1):
```

To check the scipy version, do this:

```
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.10.1'
```

Comment: I even have '0.9.0' :( Thanks for help!